# Visual Studio 2015 reinicia ao criar um arquivo Report

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, relatório, reportviewer

Sempre que eu tento criar um arquivo Report no meu projeto, o Visual Studio 2015 apresenta as seguintes mensagens:

[image: Erros que aparecem.]

Como eu poderia solucionar isso?

Comment: Ja tentaste através do report wizard? O erro é o mesmo? Tenta criar um projecto novo e adicionar o report. Continuas com o mesmo erro? Que versão de sql estás a usar?

Comment: Já sim, ao abrir a tela do Report Wizard já dar o mesmo erro. Já tentei criar um novo projeto também, e recebo o mesmo erro. Às vezes, as mensagens 2 e 3 não aparecem, só reinicia o visual studio direto.
Utilizo banco de dados Oracle 11g por enquanto.

Comment: Bem. Para já, a minha única solução seria reinstalar Visual studio (solução típica) ...

Comment: @RenatoAfonso já tentei isso. Devo ter reinstalado umas 5 vezes, e nada.

Comment: Bem, eu fiz uma rápida pesquisa, e encontrei uma outra possibilidade para resolveres o teu problema. Tenta ver mais detalhes do erro. Se uma coisa  como:  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient, Version=10.0.0. Vais à pasta C:\Windows\Assembly. Procura por "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient"  e ve se a versão está instalada. Se não estiver instalada, tenta instalar. Ùma outra possibilidade é mandares essa situação para o : http://connect.microsoft.com/